# ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE generate csv file from controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, php-7.2

I'm trying to `generate csv` file from the controller

```
 public function generateStaffcsv(Request $request, $id)
{

    $listing = StaffListing::with('trainings')->find($id);
    $training_videos = StaffTrainingVideos::all();
    $training_ids = [];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($listing->trainings); $i++) { 
        $training = $listing->trainings[$i];
        $training_ids[$training->training_id] = [
            'id' => $training->training_id,
            'status' => $training->status,
        ];
    }

    $filename = 'training-'.strtoupper(str_random(6)).'.csv';
    $headers = array(
        "Content-type" => "text/csv; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=$filename",
        "Pragma" => "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
        "Expires" => "0"
    );
    
    $columns = array('training_description', 'training_status', 'quiz_status');

    $callback = function() use ($training_videos, $columns)
    {
        $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        fputcsv($file, $columns);

        foreach($training_videos as $training) {
            if(array_key_exists($training->id,$training_ids)){
                if(isset($training_ids[$training->id])){
                    $training_status = $training_ids[$training->id]['status'] == 1 ? 'Ongoing' : ( $training_ids[$training->id]['status'] == 2 ? 'Completed' : '' );
                    $quiz_status = $training_ids[$training->id]['status'] == 1 ? 'Not completed' : ( $training_ids[$training->id]['status'] == 2 ? 'Completed' : '' );

                    fputcsv($file, array($training->name,$training_status,$quiz_status));
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($file);

        
    };
    
    return \Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
}
```

My codes seems confusing but I just trying to generate training status of a staff*

I tried to use `dd();` just to make sure if my codes is working

just like this

```
dd($callback);
return \Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```

and I got this result

[image]

and if I removed `dd`

**ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE will show up**

Here's my blade code

```
   <form method="POST" action="{{ route('generateStaffcsv', $staffID) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   <button style="width: 300px; float:right;" type="submit" name="generate_csv" class="btn btn--primary">Generate CSV</button>
                </form>
```

I'm guessing that there's something wrong with my `response code` or `headers`

because when I used `dd();` there's no error detected on the above codes, only on response codes